# "never mind..." or "forget..."

Tags: idioms, colloquial-language

I have an expression crossing my head but I cannot find any reference on the Internet. I only found "**never mind**" in the dictionary.

I'm talking about "**forget**".

E.g. "I've never visited Paris, **never mind** the Eiffel Tower."

Could I instead formulate it as "I've never visited Paris, **forget** the Eiffel Tower."?

Comment: What meaning do you expect? There's "not forgetting " (including ).

Comment: Are you thinking of “let alone”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it should be, "I have never visited Paris,let alone the Eiffel Tower. 
or
 "I have never visited Paris, not to mention the Eiffel Tower.

Let alone/Not to mention phrase. ...  used after a statement to emphasize that because the first thing is not true or possible, the next thing cannot be true or possible either.